# SSIS changes OLE DB Source query parameter data type at runtime

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want the query to return yesterdays records and be flexible in the future if there is a need to reload x Days. Therefore project parameter DaysToReload is Int32 and value is set to -1.

Source query looks like this:

```
SELECT  * FROM State.vStateHourly S
WHERE   S.DateTime >= DATEADD(d, convert(int, ?), DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())))
```

This works as expected in multiple environments, but on one site results are really strange.

When running SQL Profiler I have found that it is checking for data type of S.DateTime column before executing the above query. The event before source query execution is:

```
set fmtonly on select S.DateTime from State.vStateHourly S where 1=2 set fmtonly off
```

After this SSIS seems to set the ? parameter to data type DateTime, since the following event in trace is:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=5
exec sp_prepare @p1 output,N'@P1 datetime',N'SET FMTONLY OFF;
select top 10  *
FROM
State.vStateHourly S

WHERE   S.DateTime >= DATEADD(d, convert(int, @P1), DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())))',1
select @p1
```

Which is followed by:

```
exec sp_execute 1,'1899-12-29 00:00:00'
```

I can not observe this behaviour in any other Environment that is available to me.

Source SQL-server version: 10.50.6529.0

SSIS Server version: 13.0.1601

Any ideas what might be causing this data type lookup and how I could stabilize the behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by moving the

```
DATEADD(d, convert(int, ?), DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())))
```

part of the WHERE statement into a DateTime variable. The variable expression looks like this:

```
DATEADD("day", @[$Project::DaysToReload]  , DATEADD("day", DATEDIFF("day",(DT_DBDATE)("1900-01-01"), GETDATE()), (DT_DBDATE)("1900-01-01")))
```

It is using the global DaysToReload parameter to create a DateTime value. Then I mapped this variable to the original Query which ended up looking like this:

```
SELECT  * FROM State.vStateHourly S
WHERE   S.DateTime >= ?
```

Now SQL profiler shows that the DB Engine is checking type of S.DateTime field and then runs the Query to compare it to datetime type variable. Result is all rows starting with midnight the day before.